# Having error in deletion of data in my database via php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete information from a database via a php script but am am getting an error.
When we enter the employee ID, the ID should be deleted. However, it doesn't delete and I get an error.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Delete a Record from MySQL Database</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $emp_id = $_POST['emp_id'];

    $sql = "DELETE employee " .
        "WHERE emp_id = $emp_id";

    mysql_select_db('test');
    $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
    if (!$retval) {
        die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Deleted data successfully\n";
    mysql_close($conn);
} else { ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
        <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
            <tr>
                <td width="100">Employee ID</td>
                <td><input name="emp_id" type="text" id="emp_id"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="100"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="100"></td>
                <td>
                    <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete"
                           value="Delete">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
```

The error I get is:

> Could not delete data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE emp_id = 1' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right syntax is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

You need to say delete from

```
$sql = "DELETE **from** employee ".
   "WHERE emp_id = $emp_id" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$sql = "DELETE from employee ".
       "WHERE emp_id = $emp_id" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is `DELETE EMPLOYEE`

What you need is `DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE`, that should do if the table structure is normal.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a syntax error!

Look, you don't want to DELETE ALL the table employee, but just one line where emp_id = $emp_id"

So that's why you need to say that you want to DELETE FROM the TABLE employee, all the rows where emp_id = $emp_id" !

Answer (score 0):

emp_id (int(11)) (primary key)

- fullname (Gena lorica)
- gender (char(6))
- drate (float)
- nworkdays (int(11))
- wtax (int(11))
- sss (int(11))
- pagibig (int(11))
- philhealth (char(7))

Front-end

- frmEmp
- lblEmpID
- txtFullName
- txtDRate
- txtNWorkDays
- lblMGross
- lblGSal
- txtWTax
- txtSSS
- txtPagibig
- cmbPHealth
- lblNIncome
- btnAdd
- btnEdit
- btnDel
- dgvEmp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).